# Facebook get user Info working on main.lua but nowhere when called inside app

Tags: facebook-graph-api, lua, ios-simulator, coronasdk, facebook-login

I am trying to get facebook's user id and name in my app. I am getting an unsual error when trying facebook login on different screen.
When I call the facebook login screen from the main.lua file, I am successfully getting the user name and id in iOS simulator's debugger as below along with some more info about errors which are not affecting the login.

Version: 3.0.0

Build: 2015.2731

iOS Simulator 9.1 (13B137)

```
Dec  1 13:04:46 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Dec  1 13:04:46 Akashs-MacBook-Pro accountsd[3184]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1
Dec  1 13:04:46 Akashs-MacBook-Pro accountsd[3184]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: Spades[7774]
Dec  1 13:04:46 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
Dec  1 13:04:46 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
Dec  1 13:04:46 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:53 --- last message repeated 3 times ---
Dec  1 13:04:53 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: Need to log in
Dec  1 13:04:53 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: -canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:///" - error: "(null)"
Dec  1 13:04:53 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:55 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec  1 13:04:55 Akashs-MacBook-Pro MobileSafari[7783]: libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:1201: Could not retrieve region info
Dec  1 13:04:55 Akashs-MacBook-Pro MobileSafari[7783]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: libxpc.dylib + 71730 [D938B614-A290-3D25-8032-8DEF8A01913A]: 0x7d
Dec  1 13:04:55 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:55 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec  1 13:04:55 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 56193 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x2
Dec  1 13:04:55 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:55 Akashs-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[3135]: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Dec  1 13:04:55 Akashs-MacBook-Pro MobileSafari[7783]: Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
Dec  1 13:04:57 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:57 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 13:04:57 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7d02d790; com.appledts.GKTapper; pid: 7774; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:04:57 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:57 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7d02d790; com.appledts.GKTapper; pid: 7774; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:04:57 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:57 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7d02d790; com.appledts.GKTapper; pid: 7774; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:04:57 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:57 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 56193 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x2
Dec  1 13:04:58 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:58 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7d02d790; com.appledts.GKTapper; pid: 7774; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:04:58 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Dec  1 13:04:58 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:58 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7d02d790; com.appledts.GKTapper; pid: 7774; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:04:58 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 13:04:58 Akashs-MacBook-Pro MobileSafari[7783]: Caching encoded userInfo to use until we are marked dirty again (UAUserActivity.m #1567)
Dec  1 13:04:58 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 13:04:58 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7d02d790; com.appledts.GKTapper; pid: 7774; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:04:58 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 13:04:58 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:04:58 Akashs-MacBook-Pro networkd[3167]: -[NETClient createSleepAssertionOfType:] IOPMAssertionCreateWithProperties failed: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:04:59 Akashs-MacBook-Pro nsurlsessiond[3151]: Task 3 for client <CFString 0x7a68b4e0 [0x1bbe098]>{contents = "com.apple.mobileassetd"} completed with error - code: -999
Dec  1 13:04:59 Akashs-MacBook-Pro MobileSafari[7783]: Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
Dec  1 13:04:59 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec  1 13:04:59 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:05:00 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 13:05:00 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:07 --- last message repeated 6 times ---
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:05:07 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 56193 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x2
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro SpringBoard[3135]: [MPUSystemMediaControls] Updating supported commands for now playing application.
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro securityd[3162]:  SecDbRecordChange db <SecDbConnection rw open> changed outside txn
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: Facebook Listener events:
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    type(session)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    name(fbconnect)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    expiration(1454138523)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    phase(login)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    token(CAALF7NOI7JwBAOhwdvV ... #249)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    isError(false)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    response()
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: event.name fbconnect
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: event.type: session
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: isError: false
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: didComplete: nil
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: response: 
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: Session Status: login
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: Already logged in with needed permissions
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: Access Token Data
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [lastRefreshed] = 1448955307.3914
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [token] = [A long token here]
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [appId] = [My app ID]
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [expiration] = 1454138523.2562
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [    DeclinedPermissions] = table: 0x804726f0
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  {
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  }
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [userId] = 933164140108321
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [grantedPermissions] = table: 0x7c13d9d0
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  {
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [1] = user_friends
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [2] = publish_actions
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [3] = public_profile
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  }
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:07 --- last message repeated 2 times ---
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: Facebook Listener events:
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    isError(false)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    type(request)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    name(fbconnect)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:    response({"id":"9331641401083 ... #41)
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: event.name fbconnect
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: event.type: request
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: isError: false
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: didComplete: nil
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: response: {"id":"933164140108321","name":"Sky Jay"}
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: Facebook Command: 6
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: User Info
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [id] = 933164140108321
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]:  [name] = Sky Jay
Dec  1 13:05:07 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[7774]: name Sky Jay
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 56193 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x2
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:05:08 --- last message repeated 1 time ---
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:08 --- last message repeated 14 times ---
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:05:08 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: Could not create or rename power assertion for <BKNewProcess: 0x7ae2a450; com.apple.mobilesafari; pid: 7783; hostpid: -1>: 0xe00002c9
Dec  1 13:05:09 --- last message repeated 4 times ---
Dec  1 13:05:09 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
```

But when I open another scene from main.lua and then call facebook login screen.. I am getting this

```
Dec  1 13:20:19 --- last message repeated 8 times ---
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]: Already logged in with needed permissions
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]: Access Token Data
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [lastRefreshed] = 1448955307.3914
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [token] = [A long token here]
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [appId] = [My app ID]
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [expiration] = 1454138523.2562
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [    DeclinedPermissions] = table: 0x787bd360
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  {
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  }
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [userId] = 933164140108321
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [grantedPermissions] = table: 0x78702b10
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  {
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [1] = user_friends
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [2] = publish_actions
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [3] = public_profile
Dec  1 13:20:19 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  }
Dec  1 13:20:24 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
Dec  1 13:20:28 --- last message repeated 5 times ---
```

which means that facebook login was successful but when i click on get user info button I am getting this

```
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]: Already logged in with needed permissions
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]: Access Token Data
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [lastRefreshed] = 1448955307.3914
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [token] = [A long token here]
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [appId] = [My app ID]
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [expiration] = 1454138523.2562
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [    DeclinedPermissions] = table: 0x7c3a6600
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  {
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  }
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [userId] = 933164140108321
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [grantedPermissions] = table: 0x7c3a65b0
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  {
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [1] = user_friends
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [2] = publish_actions
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  [3] = public_profile
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]:  }
Dec  1 13:20:28 Akashs-MacBook-Pro Spades[10091]: FBSDKLog: starting with Graph API v2.4, GET requests for /me should contain an explicit "fields" parameter
Dec  1 13:20:29 Akashs-MacBook-Pro accountsd[3184]: SecTaskLoadEntitlements failed error=22 cs_flags=200, task->pid_self=-1
Dec  1 13:20:29 Akashs-MacBook-Pro accountsd[3184]: SecTaskCopyDebugDescription: Spades[10091]
Dec  1 13:20:44 Akashs-MacBook-Pro assertiond[3139]: assertion failed: 14F27 13B137: assertiond + 13207 [2F0DDEBE-B278-35C0-8523-3236DA94649E]: 0x1
```

Till yesterday I was getting these two error also, which you can now see in the first chunk of code above where facebook user info is working, So am not sure if this is the real issue.
Normal message received by listener connection. Ignoring.
Could not successfully update network info during initialization.
As am using the Corona's sample facebook app so it should be easy to reproduce for anyone.. Just move all the main.lua code to another scene and call that scene on tap of a button.

---

Here is my facebook_login.lua file, not much different from corona's facebook sample app

```
composer = require( "composer" )
scene = composer.newScene()

-- Save info in SQL
----------------------------------------
require( "ice" )
userInfo = ice:loadBox( "userInfo" )
--userInfo:clear() -- Clear all user Data
--userInfo:store()

-- Variables
------------------------------
sW = display.contentWidth -- Screen Width
sH = display.contentHeight -- Screen Height
centerX = display.contentCenterX
centerY = display.contentCenterY

_W = display.contentWidth
_H = display.contentHeight

-- Comment out the next line when through debugging your app.
io.output():setvbuf('no') -- debug: disable output buffering for Xcode Console

widget = require("widget")
facebook = require("plugin.facebook.v4")
json = require("json")

-- Facebook Commands
fbCommand = ""; -- forward reference
LOGOUT = 1
SHOW_FEED_DIALOG = 2
SHARE_LINK_DIALOG = 3
POST_MSG = 4
POST_PHOTO = 5
GET_USER_INFO = 6
PUBLISH_INSTALL = 7

-- Layout Locations
ButtonOrigX = 160
ButtonOrigY = 300
ButtonYOffset = 35
StatusMessageY = 420 -- position of status message


-- Create Game
------------------------------
function scene:create( event )

    sceneGroup = self.view

    Rest of the code here is from Corona's facebook sample app

end

function scene:show( event )
    sceneGroup = nil
    sceneGroup = self.view
    phase = event.phase

    prevScene = composer.getSceneName( "previous" )
    if prevScene then
        composer.removeScene(prevScene)
    end

    if phase == "will" then
        -- Called when the scene is still off screen and is about to move on screen
    elseif phase == "did" then
        -- Called when the scene is now on screen
        -- 
        -- INSERT code here to make the scene come alive
        -- e.g. start timers, begin animation, play audio, etc.
    end
end

function scene:hide( event )
sceneGroup = nil
sceneGroup = self.view
phase = event.phase

if event.phase == "will" then
-- Called when the scene is on screen and is about to move off screen
--
-- INSERT code here to pause the scene
-- e.g. stop timers, stop animation, unload sounds, etc.)
elseif phase == "did" then
-- Called when the scene is now off screen
end
end

function scene:destroy( event )
sceneGroup = nil
sceneGroup = self.view

-- Called prior to the removal of scene's "view" (sceneGroup)
-- 
-- INSERT code here to cleanup the scene
-- e.g. remove display objects, remove touch listeners, save state, etc.
end

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Listener setup
scene:addEventListener( "create", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "show", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "hide", scene )
scene:addEventListener( "destroy", scene )
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

return scene
```